# Visual Studio Community Mac Task Highlighting

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, task

I install Visual Studio Community through Unity, and I noticed that the tasks (TODO, FIXME, UNDONE) don’t get highlighted when I write them. What’s wierd is that sometimes when I first open a file, TODO will be a different color than the rest of the comment, but after everything is done loading, the TODO will become the same font and color as the rest of the comment again.

How do I get tasks to remain highlighted in Visual Studio?

(I am using unity on a Mac, and this version of VS Community was installed by the unity installer)